# Check if property or method exists at runtime? Check if Trait exists at runtime?

Tags: methods, properties, rust, traits

Looking for the proper way to do

```
if(self.MyProperty) { /* ... */ }
```

> error: attempted access of field `MyProperty` on type `MyType`, but no field with that name was found

or

```
if(self.MyMethod){ /* ... */ }
```

> error: attempted to take value of method `MyMethod` on type `MyType`

As a last resort, at least how does one check if a Trait is Implemented?

Comment: These are compile-time errors; why would you need any other way of checking for them?

Comment: I was posting the errors for the description. I just may need to check for these at run-time because my elements are heterogeneous and there is some dynamic logic, for example, handling events. Does rust support checking for existing fields or methods?

Comment: How are your elements heterogenous? Do you have `Vec<Box<Trait>>`?

Comment: yes that's what i'm using -- and it delegates from that traits method into others, like self.Controller.Method1. I am still in the desigining phase and new to Rust.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This concept doesn't exist in Rust. While there is some limited downcast capability through `Any`, this should be used as a last resort. What you should do is create a new trait that exposes all of these decisions for you.

Reusing your example of a `my_method` method:

```
trait YourTrait {
    fn try_my_method(&self, arg: SomeArg) -> Option<MyMethodResult> {
        None
    }
}

impl YourTrait for SomeType {
    fn try_my_method(&self, arg: SomeArg) -> Option<MyMethodResult> {
        Some(self.my_method(arg))
    }
}
```

In your code you can then call

```
if let Some(result) = self.try_my_method() {
    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: OK. Thanks for the answer. I have seen this before, but it would not work for a fully modular design. Hopefully I just do not need to check at run-time anyway.

Comment: (For example, if new Traits are created for a particular element, then all elements would then need essentially this "empty" trait to compensate)

Comment: @HTDE are you sure you don't want to use an enum? Another alternative is to offer a `fn has_my_xyztrait(&self) -> Option<&XYZTrait>` which downcasts to a specific trait that only some elements might implement. This way you only have to do this per trait, instead of per method or field.

Comment: Note: you should definitely use an enum if users of your library don't ever need to create new element types.

Comment: I agree! I am trying to understand the first comment about downcasting to a specific trait. Is there an example or documentation I can view? Thanks!

Comment: You just found the limitation: downcasting is only possible to types, not traits. The docs are the docs of the `Any` trait.